# Is it possible to validate an expression using preprocessor directives ? like #if (a == b)

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

To be precise I need to check a function pointer against null pointer. I need a part of a code to be compiled only if the function pointer is mapped to a valid function and not to a null pointer. Is it possible in c ?

something similar to :

```
#if (function_pointer != NULLpointer)
{
// Code block to be compiled
}
```

Comment: Feels like this might be an XY problem. Can you show the code that assigns `function_pointer`?

Comment: How would your preprocessor know if a function pointer is mapped? Instead of using a function pointer, you could `#define FUNCTION_TO_USE` as your function, and then do `#ifndef FUNCTION_TO_USE`

Comment: You want the preprocessor to know how your code will execute. You are asking too much of it. The poor little text substitition engine doesn't even know what code *is*.

Comment: It is most likely that the C preprocessor will think that both `function_pointer` and `NULLpointer` are zero (integer zero) and therefore that they are 'the same value'.  Function addresses aren't known until link time at the earliest — that's the other end of the compilation process from the preprocessing phase.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. That's a run-time evaluation. So the logic is:

```
if (function_pointer != NULL)
{
   // Code block to be executed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding this is *not* possible due to conceptual reasons because the sketched condition can be evaluated only at runtime, while the decision for inclusion and exclusion of code must be done at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do it like this:

```
#define mapped // compiler switch, comment-out if function_pointer shouldn't be used

#ifdef mapped
  type function_pointer = something;
#else
  type function_pointer = NULL;
#endif

...

#ifdef mapped
  /* code to compile here */
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several steps in the compilation and running process. The full list is a bit daunting, but simplified it looks like this

1. Preprocessing
2. Compilation
3. Linking
4. Running

They are executed sequentially. Since there is no time travel, a latter step cannot influence a preceding one.

So preprocessing cannot use your function pointer value because function pointer values do not exist until the program is ran. A preprocessor can only make decisions based on values availabe at preprocessing time. All such values are integers. They all must be literals, expressions made up of literals, or something `#define`d in terms of those.

Answer (score -1):

This depends on the nature of the function pointer that you're checking. If the function pointer ever changes while the program is running, checking its value at compile time cannot be done.

However, if your function pointer is defined at compile-time and never changes, you can declare it as a `const` variable. Constant expressions can be used in preprocessor conditions, so code like this is legal:

```
const int *a = NULL;               

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
#if a == 0                         
  printf("null\n");                
#else                              
  printf("not null\n");            
#endif                             
  return 0;                        
}
```

The assembly code generated from this would be equivalent to that generated from:

```
const int *a = NULL;               

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {                
  printf("null\n");                 
  return 0;                        
}
```

EDIT: @serge is right: this only works coincidentally. You may still be able to make some gains by making your function pointer const if your compiler can optimize away the unreachable branch of the conditional, but it won't be the same as removing the code with a preprocessor condition.

Comment: this is wrong. it only works because undefined macro `a` is interpreted as `0` by the standard.